# How to parse the text file in c#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace readfrom_textfile {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Practise\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                string line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    string[] data = line.Split(new char[] {
                        '('
                    }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string bikeName = data[0].Trim().Split(' ').Last();
                    bikeName = bikeName.Remove(bikeName.Length - 1);
                    string[] usageData = data[1].Split(new char[] {
                        ';'
                    }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string issuedBike = usageData[0].Trim().Split(' ')[2];
                    string inUseBike = usageData[1].Trim().Split(' ')[2];
                    Console.WriteLine("Name:" + bikeName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Total:" + issuedBike);
                    Console.WriteLine("InUse:" + inUseBike);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

In my text file the line is:

> Users of Yamaha: (Total of 2 bike issued; Total of 2 bike in use).newline
>           line1....................something[newline]
>           line2..................something[newline]
>           Bike details
>           //emptyline
>           1125 Monica YamahaR15(v3.0)(petrol / 7788 4903), start Wed 1 / 18 8: 53
>           1128 Dhini Yamaha Fz(v2.0)(petrol / 7748 4903), start Wed 1 / 18 9: 53

```
    This is the line.I want to get this line from my file and split into < pre >
        Name: Yamaha;
    Total: 1;
    Inuse: 1;
    members: Monica[Wed 1 / 18 8: 53], dhini[Wed 1 / 18 9: 53] < /pre>
    Like this format.
```

Comment: How the actual content of the file Looks like? add at least two example lines

Comment: Users of Yamaha:  (Total of 1 bike issued;  Total of 1 bike in use) ;                     Users of Hero:  (Total of 6 bike issued;  Total of 2 bike in use);

Comment: Lines is in single line or multiple lines ?

Comment: The lines are multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing each record in nextline in txt file (1 line per 1 record) like:

```
Users of Yamaha: (Total of 1 bike issued; Total of 1 bike in use)
Users of Hero: (Total of 6 bike issued; Total of 2 bike in use)
```

then you can do using the following code which also stores the output in a file.

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
   var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Practise\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
   {
      string line;
      string createTextFile = "";
      string outputPath = @"D:\Practise\Output.txt";
      while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         string[] data = line.Split(new char[] { '(' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         string bikeName = data[0].Trim().Split(' ').Last();
         bikeName = bikeName.Remove(bikeName.Length - 1);
         string[] usageData = data[1].Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         string issuedBike = usageData[0].Trim().Split(' ')[2];
         string inUseBike = usageData[1].Trim().Split(' ')[2];

         Console.WriteLine("Name:" + bikeName);
         Console.WriteLine("Total:" + issuedBike);
         Console.WriteLine("InUse:" + inUseBike);
         Console.WriteLine();

         createTextFile += "Name:" + bikeName + Environment.NewLine;
         createTextFile += "Total:" + issuedBike + Environment.NewLine;
         createTextFile += "InUse:" + inUseBike + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
      }
      File.WriteAllText(outputPath, createTextFile);
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Error populating:Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: Its great @Pranav Patel

Comment: I had a another doubt .How to append this to a text file.

Comment: for example? you want to store output in textfile ?

Comment: Yes .I want to store the o/p in a text file

Comment: I Updated my question .I don't know to solve that.Please help me to solve the problem @Pranav Patel